# Does $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}=\textbf{a}^T\textbf{b}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763122/dot-product-with-vector-and-its-transpose), does $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}=\textbf{a}^T\textbf{b}$?

Comment: It occurs to me that despite my answer, there is a subtle difference between them: $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b$ is a scalar, that is, an element of the underlying structure of the matrix space, but $\mathbf a^T \mathbf b$ is an order $1$ matrix. The two behave similarly, but technically speaking you can't multiply an $n \times m$ matrix by a $1 \times 1$ matrix using conventional matrix multiplication -- but you can multiply an $n \times m$ matrix by a scalar.

Comment: @PrimeMover As I have observed many times, there is a distinction between a scalar $x$ and the $1\times 1$ matrix $(x)$,  but maintaining that distinction is in practice virtually impossible :-)

Comment: @AnginaSeng Maintaining the distinction is probably not important. Being **aware** of it is another thing altogether, and it probably *is* important at least to understand the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are column vectors, then yes.

The transpose of a column vector is a row vector.

Then the identity trivially follows from the definitions of transpose and matrix product.

Comment: Thank you so much!